# Securing URL with user owned resources in OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm aware of how OAuth2 and OIDC can use custom scopes and token introspection to secure an URL like this:

```
/users/me/documents
```

I can give this URL the `documents:view` scope and when receiving the token from the authenticated user, I can ask the authorization server if this user has the correct permissions. Then I can use the `preferred_username` claim or similar to see who `/me` actually is.

But what if I have a resource which is accessible by multiple users? Let's say a user has documents but they can be viewed by his direct manager. To retrieve the employee's documents as a manager, I'd need to have an url like this:

```
/users/${userId}/documents
```

How could I enforce it in a way that **only the resource owner and direct manager** can view this resource? I don't want everyone to access everyone's documents by knowing the `userId`. I could grant access as a whole to all users with the `manager` role, but that's not specific enough.

I'm aware there's the [`UMA`](https://docs.kantarainitiative.org/uma/wg/rec-oauth-uma-grant-2.0.html) extension where users can grant access to resources on his behalf to other users, but it's not the user who grants permission. It's the system who states in this case that managers can access their employees documents.

Would it make sense to write a custom policy which extracts the `${userId}` and performs the check? Or should this not be done by the authorization server at all and be done by the resource server instead? Perhaps a different approach to reach the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finer grained authorization like this is done with claims rather than scopes. There may be business rules around which docs a user can see, eg:

- A user can access their own docs
- An admin has view access to all docs
- A manager can view docs for people they manage

In an access token this might be represented by these claims:

- userId
- role

Claims are often domain specific like this and the preferred option is to add them to tokens during token issuance. At Curity we have some good resources on this topic:

- [Claims Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/)

**CLAIMS AND AUTHORIZATION**

The Authorization Server issues access tokens and then APIs (resource servers) verify the access token and use the token data to apply authorization rules (which are often domain specific) on every single request.

Claims are often used when dynamic behaviour is needed - they are runtime values that derive from the user identity, whereas scopes are fixed design time values. In your example an API might also need to vary SQL to retrieve documents based on the user identity.

There are more complex variations on this theme, such as an API calling a system such as [Open Policy Agent](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa), so that documents returned are determined by rules configured by a security administrator. That policy would still involve using claims from the access token though.

**EXAMPLE CODE**

If it helps, here is [some sample code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/src/logic/services/companyService.ts) that show the type of approach when enforcing domain specific authorization rules. Typically you need to filter collections and check access to individual items.

Comment: The `userId` claim is present in the token, but is it the responsibility of the resource server to validate access? E.g., the manager invokes `/user/${userId}/documents` and the resource server retrieves the resource and checks access afterwards? Or is this the responsibility of the authorization server? I see the authorization server as the PDP who decides on all authorization decisions. Adding a claim seems to shift this back to the resource server.

Comment: Yes - the resource server should verify access - on every request using the access token. The terminology a little confusing because an 'Authorization Server' does not actually do authorization. See the updated section in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for extending your answer. I think the [Keycloak policies](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_policy_overview) made me lean more towards putting all authorization inside the AS. But I suppose that's for more general policies and not business-specific ones.